# Flutter Channel to pass iOS Data encoded in base64

Tags: swift, flutter, base64, apple-wallet

I'm implementing a `PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate` In Swift.
Since I'm using Flutter, I need to pass over some Data which is Base64 encoded (`certificates` Which is an array, `nonce` and `nonceSignature`).
When I invoke a method with this data, should I decoder it to send it to the flutter layer and then reencode it to make the network request or will the standard binary Messenger support sending the encoded String?

What I have written so far:

```
public func addPaymentPassViewController(
                                    _ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController,
                                    generateRequestWithCertificateChain certificates: [Data],
                                    nonce: Data,
                                    nonceSignature: Data,
                                    completionHandler handler: @escaping (PKAddPaymentPassRequest) -> Void) {

flutterChannel.invokeMethod("provisionRequest",
            arguments: [
               "certificates": certificates,
               "nonce": nonce,
               "nonceSignature": nonceSignature,
            ]) {
                responseData in
                let data = responseData as! [String: Any]
                let addPaymentPassRequest = PKAddPaymentPassRequest()
                addPaymentPassRequest.encryptedPassData = Data(base64Encoded: data["passData"], options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
                addPaymentPassRequest.activationData = Data(base64Encoded: data["activationData"], options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
                addPaymentPassRequest.ephemeralPublicKey = Data(base64Encoded: data["ephemeralKey"], options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
                handler(addPaymentPassRequest)
            }
```

Comment: The standard message codec handles several primitives like numbers, booleans, strings, byte arrays - plus lists and maps of supported primitives. See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html If you have byte arrays, you could pass them directly. You could also b64 encode them as pass them as strings (with a slight loss of efficiency).

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for your comment. So what I did is basically correct. Though using directly the swift Data type, what will be the corresponding type on the dart side? Since I will need a base64 string on the flutter side, I guess encoding it directly on the swift side won't result in any loss of efficiency in my case

Comment: See the link above. It shows the correspondence between iOS, Android and Dart types.